# jUnit ErrorCollector reports duplicate rows

Tags: java, junit

I found the below example from jUnit wiki. I expect that the error table should constantly report two errors. But sometimes it reports the second error twice.  Any explanation?

```
    public class ErrorCollectorRuleTest {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void example() {
        collector.addError(new Throwable("first thing went wrong"));
        collector.addError(new Throwable("second thing went wrong"));
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Completed
java.lang.Throwable: first thing went wrong
java.lang.Throwable: second thing went wrong
java.lang.Throwable: second thing went wrong
```

Comment: How do you runt the test: Maven, Eclipse, command-line, ...?

Comment: @StefanBirkner  Intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is an IntelliJ Idea bug. See https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/1104

Comment: Thanks !   The test case runs fine in Eclipse, but not IntelliJ IDEA.